# Struggling to understand the Where Statement solution to a SQLZoo problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been working my way through SQLzoo's project HelpDesk and I'm struggling to understand the last line of the solution i've found online. The question is as follows:

80/20 rule. It is said that 80% of the calls are generated by 20% of the callers. Is this true? What percentage of calls are generated by the most active 20% of callers.

I found a solution when i got stumped but I'm struggling with the math in the final line. How exactly does that line ensure that the counter only works for the top 20%?

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(b.calls_per_caller / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Issue) * 100), 4) as t20pc
FROM (
   SELECT a.*, @counter := @counter + 1 AS counter
   FROM
      (SELECT @counter := 0) AS initvar,
      (SELECT caller_id, COUNT(*) AS calls_per_caller
         FROM Issue
         GROUP BY caller_id
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS a
) AS b
WHERE counter <= (20/100 * @counter)
```

To my understanding, the counter could be 30 for example, and plugging 30 in for @counter on the right side of the where statement would come out to 6 which is less than 30. So 30 <= 6 is not true so 30 doesn't work, but i get a similar answer if i choose a counter that is below 20. If the counter is 10, so in the top 10%, the Where statement reads 10 <= 2 which is also not true. Am i misunderstanding something with the difference between @counter and counter, or is there something with the math I'm not getting?

This solution works, i'm just struggling to understand how that last line gives me the top 20%

Reference link :
https://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Hard_Questions

Comment: In `b`, there is a `counter` column which starts from 1 to the total number of rows. And `@counter` here is the total number of rows since you have been doing `@counter := @counter + 1`. 


Imagine you have 100 rows in `b` with counter 1 - 100, you do `WHERE counter <= (20/100 * @counter)`, this would translate to `WHERE counter <= (20/100 * 100)`, so you would only end up with the first 20 rows. In other words, `counter` is the column, `@counter` is the variable